# Does the Sale of Goods Act continue to be applicable to second-hand items bought from private individuals rather than professional traders in 2023?

Tags: england-and-wales, sale-of-goods

I have been told that the Consumer Rights Act 2015 only supersedes the Sale of Goods Act 1979 for second-hand items bought from companies, and not ones bought from individuals. Is this correct?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I learn information about the purpose, background, and other context of recent U.K. legislation?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/91609/how-can-i-learn-information-about-the-purpose-background-and-other-context-of)

Comment: Not even nearly.

Answer (score 2):

The Consumer Rights Act 2015 does not apply to goods other than those [sold by a trader to a consumer](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2015/15/section/3).

Almost always (as demonstrated in [several](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/91608/46948) [other](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/92414/46948) [answers](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/91609/46948)), the interaction between related legislation is explained in [explanatory notes](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/91609/46948). In this case, [they say](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2015/15/notes/division/2/5):

> The [Sale of Goods Act] will still apply to... consumer to consumer contracts